# About multipass sort algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I am reading *Programming Pearls* by Jon Bentley ([reference](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/sec013.html)).

Here author is mentioning about various sorting algorithms like merge sort, multipass sort.

Questions:

1. How does algorithm for merge sort work by reading input file once and using work files  and writing output file only once?
2. How does the author denote that the 40 pass i.e. multipass sort algorithm works by writing only once to output file and with no work files?

Can someone explain the above with a simple example, like having memory to store 3 digits and having 10 digits to store, e.g. `9,0,8,6,5,4,1,2,3,7`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from Chapter 1 of Jon Bentley's
[Programming Pearls, 2nd Edn](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/0201657880/) (1999), which is an excellent book.  The equivalent example from the first edition is slightly different; the multipass algorithm only made 27 passes over the data (and there was less memory available).

The sort described by Jon Bentley has special setup constraints.

- File contains at most 10 million records.
- Each record is a 7 digit number.
- There is no other data associated with the records.
- There is only 1 MiB of memory available when the sort must be done.

#### Question 1

The single read of the input file slurps as many lines from the input as will fit in memory, sorts that data, and writes it out to a work file. Rinse and repeat until there is no more data in the input file.

Then, complete the process by reading the work files and merging the sorted contents into a single output file. In extreme cases, it might be necessary to create new, bigger work files because the program can't read all the work files at once. If that happens, you arrange for the final pass to have the maximum number of inputs that can be handled, and have the intermediate passes merge appropriate numbers of files.

This is a general purpose algorithm.

#### Question 2

This is where the peculiar properties of the data are exploited.  Since the numbers are unique and limited in range, the algorithm can read the file the first time, extracting numbers from the first fortieth of the range, sorting and writing those; then it extracts the second fortieth of the range, then the third, ..., then the last fortieth.

This is a special-purpose algorithm, exploiting the nature of the numbers.