# Why does the following golang program throw a runtime out of memory error?

Tags: go, out-of-memory, runtime-error

This program is supposed to read a file consisting of pairs of ints (one pair per line) and remove duplicate pairs. While it works on small files, it throws a runtime error on huge files (say a file of 1.5 GB). Initially, I thought that it is the map data structure which is causing this, but even after commenting it out, it still runs out of memory. Any ideas why this is happening? How to rectify it? Here's a data file on which it runs out of memory: http://snap.stanford.edu/data/com-Orkut.html

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "bufio"
    "os"
    "strings"
    "strconv"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer file.Close()
    type Edge struct {
        u, v int
    }
    //seen := make(map[Edge]bool)
    edges := []Edge{}
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for i, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2]); i > 0; i-- {
        scanner.Scan()
    }

    for scanner.Scan() {
        str := scanner.Text()
        edge := strings.Split(str, ",")
        u, _ := strconv.Atoi(edge[0])
        v, _ := strconv.Atoi(edge[1])
        var key Edge
        if u < v {
            key = Edge{u,v}
        } else {
            key = Edge{v,u}
        }
        //if seen[key] {
        //  continue
        //}
        //seen[key] = true
        edges = append(edges, key)
    }
    for _, e := range edges {
        s := strconv.Itoa(e.u) + "," + strconv.Itoa(e.v)
        fmt.Println(s)
    }
}
```

A sample input is given below. The program can be run as follows (where the last input says how many lines to skip).
go run undup.go a.txt 1

```
# 3072441,117185083
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8
```

Comment: how much memory does you machine have?

Comment: Even when commenting out the map.. you still have that slice thats going to become huge depending on the input. That is, 3 WORD size references for housekeeping of the slice .. plus one WORD size reference for each entry. Then, each append creates a new slice and copies the content of the other one into the new one.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead You are correct. I got rid of the slice and still it ran out of memory. I checked (on Mac OSX activity monitor) and found out that the program grows well beyond 1.2 GB of memory after which it throws error. I realized despite 8GB of memory on my machine, there was only around 1GB of memory left. I think the problem lies less with the code and more with the dataset that I am reading which is 1.6GB on disk.

Comment: Also consider multiple passes.  It may be that you simply can't represent this data as a single, in-memory structure.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19908791/about-multipass-sort-algorithm as an example of a multi-pass approach, and read: http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/cto.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I looked at this file: `com-orkut.ungraph.txt` and it contains 117,185,082 lines. The way your data is structured, that's at least 16 bytes per line. (Edge is two 64bit ints) That alone is 1.7GB. I have had this problem in the past, and it can be a tricky one. Are you trying to solve this for a specific use case (the file in question) or the general case?

In the specific case there are a few things about the data you could leverage: (1) the keys are sorted and (2) it looks it stores every connection twice, (3) the numbers don't seem huge. Here are a couple ideas:

1. If you use a smaller type for the key you will use less memory. Try a `uint32`.
2. You could stream (without using a map) the keys to another file by simply seeing if the 2nd column is greater than the first:

   ```
   if u < v {
       // write the key to another file
   } else {
       // skip it because v will eventually show v -> u
   }
   ```

For the general case there are a couple strategies you could use:

1. If the order of the resulting list doesn't matter: Use an on-disk hash table to store the map. There are a bunch of these: leveldb, sqlite, tokyo tyrant, ... A really nice one for go is [bolt](https://github.com/boltdb/bolt).

   In your for loop you would just check to see if a bucket contains the given key. (You can convert the ints into byte slices using encoding/binary) If it does, just skip it and continue. You will need to move the second for loop processing step into the first for loop so that you don't have to store all the keys.
2. If the order of the resulting list does matter (and you can't guarantee the input is in order): You can also use an on-disk hash table, but it needs to be sorted. Bolt is sorted so that will work. Add all the keys to it, then traverse it in the second loop.

Here is an example: (this program will take a while to run with 100 million records)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "encoding/binary"
    "fmt"
    "github.com/boltdb/bolt"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

type Edge struct {
    u, v int
}

func FromKey(bs []byte) Edge {
    return Edge{int(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(bs[:8])), int(binary.BigEndian.Uint64(bs[8:]))}
}

func (e Edge) Key() [16]byte {
    var k [16]byte
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(k[:8], uint64(e.u))
    binary.BigEndian.PutUint64(k[8:], uint64(e.v))
    return k
}

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open(os.Args[1])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)

    for i, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Args[2]); i > 0; i-- {
        scanner.Scan()
    }

    db, _ := bolt.Open("ex.db", 0777, nil)
    defer db.Close()

    bucketName := []byte("edges")
    db.Update(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        tx.CreateBucketIfNotExists(bucketName)
        return nil
    })

    batchSize := 10000
    total := 0
    batch := make([]Edge, 0, batchSize)
    writeBatch := func() {
        total += len(batch)
        fmt.Println("write batch. total:", total)
        db.Update(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
            bucket := tx.Bucket(bucketName)
            for _, edge := range batch {
                key := edge.Key()
                bucket.Put(key[:], nil)
            }
            return nil
        })
    }

    for scanner.Scan() {
        str := scanner.Text()
        edge := strings.Split(str, "\t")
        u, _ := strconv.Atoi(edge[0])
        v, _ := strconv.Atoi(edge[1])
        var key Edge
        if u < v {
            key = Edge{u, v}
        } else {
            key = Edge{v, u}
        }
        batch = append(batch, key)
        if len(batch) == batchSize {
            writeBatch()
            // reset the batch length to 0
            batch = batch[:0]
        }
    }
    // write anything leftover
    writeBatch()

    db.View(func(tx *bolt.Tx) error {
        tx.Bucket(bucketName).ForEach(func(k, v []byte) error {
            edge := FromKey(k)
            fmt.Println(edge)
            return nil
        })
        return nil
    })
}
```

Comment: I haven't tried the solution yet, but it looks like a great strategy. Will try and report back!

Answer (score 2):

You are squandering memory. Here's how to rectify it.

You give the sample input `a.txt`, 48 bytes.

```
# 3072441,117185083
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
```

On http://snap.stanford.edu/data/com-Orkut.html, I found http://snap.stanford.edu/data/bigdata/communities/com-orkut.ungraph.txt.gz, 1.8 GB uncompressed, 117,185,083 edges.

```
# Undirected graph: ../../data/output/orkut.txt
# Orkut
# Nodes: 3072441 Edges: 117185083
# FromNodeId    ToNodeId
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
```

On http://socialnetworks.mpi-sws.org/data-imc2007.html, I found http://socialnetworks.mpi-sws.mpg.de/data/orkut-links.txt.gz, 3.4 GB uncompressed, 223,534,301 edges.

```
1   2
1   3
1   4
1   5
```

Since they are similar, one program can handle all formats.

Your `Edge` type is

```
type Edge struct {
    u, v int
}
```

which is 16 bytes on a 64-bit architecture.

Use

```
type Edge struct {
    U, V uint32
}
```

which is 8 bytes, it is adequate.

If the capacity of a slice is not large enough to fit the additional values, `append` allocates a new, sufficiently large underlying array that fits both the existing slice elements and the additional values. Otherwise, `append` re-uses the underlying array. For a large slice, the new array is 1.25 times the size of the old array. While the old array is being copied to the new array, 1 + 1.25 = 2.25 times the memory for the old array is required. Therefore, allocate the underlying array so that all values fit.

`make(T, n)` initializes map of type T with initial space for n elements. Provide a value for n to limit the cost of reorganization and fragmentation as elements are added. Hashing functions are often imperfect which leads to wasted space. Eliminate the map as it's unneccesary. To eliminate duplicates, sort the slice in place and move the unique elements down.

A `string` is immutable, therefore a new `string` is allocated for `scanner.Text()` to convert from a `byte` slice buffer. To parse numbers we use `strconv`. To minimize temporary allocations, use `scanner.Bytes()` and adapt `strconv.ParseUint` to accept a byte array argument (`bytconv`).

For example,

`orkut.go`

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "runtime"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
)

type Edge struct {
    U, V uint32
}

func (e Edge) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%d,%d", e.U, e.V)
}

type ByKey []Edge

func (a ByKey) Len() int      { return len(a) }
func (a ByKey) Swap(i, j int) { a[i], a[j] = a[j], a[i] }
func (a ByKey) Less(i, j int) bool {
    if a[i].U < a[j].U {
        return true
    }
    if a[i].U == a[j].U && a[i].V < a[j].V {
        return true
    }
    return false
}

func countEdges(scanner *bufio.Scanner) int {
    var nNodes, nEdges int
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Bytes()
        if !(len(line) > 0 && line[0] == '#') {
            nEdges++
            continue
        }
        n, err := fmt.Sscanf(string(line), "# Nodes: %d Edges: %d", &nNodes, &nEdges)
        if err != nil || n != 2 {
            n, err = fmt.Sscanf(string(line), "# %d,%d", &nNodes, &nEdges)
            if err != nil || n != 2 {
                continue
            }
        }
        fmt.Println(string(line))
        break
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println(nEdges)
    return nEdges
}

func loadEdges(filename string) []Edge {
    file, err := os.Open(filename)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    defer file.Close()

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(file)
    nEdges := countEdges(scanner)
    edges := make([]Edge, 0, nEdges)
    offset, err := file.Seek(0, os.SEEK_SET)
    if err != nil || offset != 0 {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    var sep byte = '\t'
    scanner = bufio.NewScanner(file)
    for scanner.Scan() {
        line := scanner.Bytes()
        if len(line) > 0 && line[0] == '#' {
            continue
        }
        i := bytes.IndexByte(line, sep)
        if i < 0 || i+1 >= len(line) {
            sep = ','
            i = bytes.IndexByte(line, sep)
            if i < 0 || i+1 >= len(line) {
                err := errors.New("Invalid line format: " + string(line))
                panic(err.Error())
            }
        }
        u, err := ParseUint(line[:i], 10, 32)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        v, err := ParseUint(line[i+1:], 10, 32)
        if err != nil {
            panic(err.Error())
        }
        if u > v {
            u, v = v, u
        }
        edges = append(edges, Edge{uint32(u), uint32(v)})
    }
    if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
        panic(err.Error())
    }

    if len(edges) <= 1 {
        return edges
    }
    sort.Sort(ByKey(edges))
    j := 0
    i := j + 1
    for ; i < len(edges); i, j = i+1, j+1 {
        if edges[i] == edges[j] {
            break
        }
    }
    for ; i < len(edges); i++ {
        if edges[i] != edges[j] {
            j++
            edges[j] = edges[i]
        }
    }
    edges = edges[:j+1]
    return edges
}

func main() {
    if len(os.Args) <= 1 {
        err := errors.New("Missing file name")
        panic(err.Error())
    }
    filename := os.Args[1]
    fmt.Println(filename)
    edges := loadEdges(filename)

    var ms runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&ms)
    fmt.Println(ms.Alloc, ms.TotalAlloc, ms.Sys, ms.Mallocs, ms.Frees)
    fmt.Println(len(edges), cap(edges))
    for i, e := range edges {
        fmt.Println(e)
        if i >= 10 {
            break
        }
    }
}

// bytconv from strconv

// Return the first number n such that n*base >= 1<<64.
func cutoff64(base int) uint64 {
    if base < 2 {
        return 0
    }
    return (1<<64-1)/uint64(base) + 1
}

// ParseUint is like ParseInt but for unsigned numbers.
func ParseUint(s []byte, base int, bitSize int) (n uint64, err error) {
    var cutoff, maxVal uint64

    if bitSize == 0 {
        bitSize = int(strconv.IntSize)
    }

    s0 := s
    switch {
    case len(s) < 1:
        err = strconv.ErrSyntax
        goto Error

    case 2 <= base && base <= 36:
        // valid base; nothing to do

    case base == 0:
        // Look for octal, hex prefix.
        switch {
        case s[0] == '0' && len(s) > 1 && (s[1] == 'x' || s[1] == 'X'):
            base = 16
            s = s[2:]
            if len(s) < 1 {
                err = strconv.ErrSyntax
                goto Error
            }
        case s[0] == '0':
            base = 8
        default:
            base = 10
        }

    default:
        err = errors.New("invalid base " + strconv.Itoa(base))
        goto Error
    }

    n = 0
    cutoff = cutoff64(base)
    maxVal = 1<<uint(bitSize) - 1

    for i := 0; i < len(s); i++ {
        var v byte
        d := s[i]
        switch {
        case '0' <= d && d <= '9':
            v = d - '0'
        case 'a' <= d && d <= 'z':
            v = d - 'a' + 10
        case 'A' <= d && d <= 'Z':
            v = d - 'A' + 10
        default:
            n = 0
            err = strconv.ErrSyntax
            goto Error
        }
        if int(v) >= base {
            n = 0
            err = strconv.ErrSyntax
            goto Error
        }

        if n >= cutoff {
            // n*base overflows
            n = 1<<64 - 1
            err = strconv.ErrRange
            goto Error
        }
        n *= uint64(base)

        n1 := n + uint64(v)
        if n1 < n || n1 > maxVal {
            // n+v overflows
            n = 1<<64 - 1
            err = strconv.ErrRange
            goto Error
        }
        n = n1
    }

    return n, nil

Error:
    return n, &strconv.NumError{"ParseUint", string(s0), err}
}
```

Output:

```
$ go build orkut.go
$ time ./orkut ~/release-orkut-links.txt
/home/peter/release-orkut-links.txt
223534301
1788305680 1788327856 1904683256 135 50
117185083 223534301
1,2
1,3
1,4
1,5
1,6
1,7
1,8
1,9
1,10
1,11
1,12
real    2m53.203s
user    2m51.584s
sys 0m1.628s
$
```

The `orkut.go` program with the `release-orkut-links.txt` file (3,372,855,860 (3.4 GB) bytes with 223,534,301 edges) uses about 1.8 GiB of memory. After eliminating duplicates, 117,185,083 unique edges remain. This matches the 117,185,083 unique edge `com-orkut.ungraph.txt` file.

With 8 GB of memory on your machine, you can load much larger files.

Comment: Wow! This is so helpful. I'll give it a shot on my dataset (which is essentially the same as the one you used).